# mongodb $pull doesn't work with array in subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have a problem with an update with MongoDB.

My schema look like this:

```
Project: {
    _id: ObjectId(pro_id)
    // some data
    dashboard_group: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId(dgr_id)
            dgr_name: "My Dashboard"
            dgr_tasks: [
                id1,
                id2,
                ...
            ]
        },
        // other dashboards
    ]
}
```

I want to remove id2 but the $pull operator seems not work. Mongo return me this :

```
result: {
    lastErrorObject: {
        n: 1,
        updatedExisting: true
    },
    ok: 1
}
```

This is my request:

```
db.Project.findOneAndUpdate({
    "dashboard_group._id": dgr_id
}, {
    $pull: {
        "dashboard_group.$.dgr_tasks": id2
    }
});
```

dgr_id is already cast to ObjectId before the query and I verified the value that I want to remove.

Can anyone have an idea ?

Comment: your query looks good to me. It may the input values that have some issues. What about id2 ? Is it also ObjectId ?

Comment: Yes, i cast id2 in ObjectId before my request, i console.log() the input before the query too, and all looks good, even the response of Mongo says that the document has been updated. But when I check my database, the value is still here

Comment: Are you positive id2 is being saved in the database as type `ObjectId`?

Comment: Yes, when I push my value in the array, I create a new ObjectId, there is no other type in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to select the particular array element using `"$elemMatch"` like this

Query : `{"dashboard_group":{"$elemMatch":{dgr_name:"My Dashboard"}}}`

Update : `{$pull:{"dashboard_group.$.dgr_tasks":"id2"}}`

Comment: Mine is working. In the query, did you try with "_id" or "dgr_name" ?

Comment: I tried with the _id, i'll try with the dgr_name like your query to see if it change the result. Did you try with multiple "dashboard_group" in the collection ?

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a solution with the `$[]` identifier. It's not its basic utility, but it fit to my case.

A task ID cannot be at 2 location, it  belongs to 1 and only 1 dashboard. So if you make a request like :

```
db.Project.findOneAndModify({
    "dashboard_group._id": dgr_id
}, {
    $pull: {
        "dashboard_group.$[].dgr_tasks": id2   
    }
});
```

Mongo will remove all value that match id2. Without the `{multi: true}` option, it will make the update 1 time, and my item is indeed remove from my nested array.